# Does undeletion reset the RemoveDeadQuestions clock?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user, undelete, auto-delete

A ~35 day old question with no votes or answers received a downvote resulting in a score of -1, and was [deleted under the `RemoveDeadQuestions` criterion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/172266).  I have voted to undelete such a question.  Suppose it gets undeleted, how will it be treated by the `RemoveDeadQuestions` directive?  Will the 30-day clock start counting from the time of undeletion, or will the Community user delete the question as soon as it is undeleted, it being after all a question older than 30 days?

Comment: IIRC correctly the 30 days script will run once a week, on Saturday 03:00 UTC and it will remove any question that meet the criteria. So after being undeleted it could fall victim to the roomba as soon as the script runs. The undelete event doesn't start a new 30 day clock.

Comment: In my opinion, a single downvote shouldn't be a unilateral delete vote. That deletion criterion should be made narrower, to prevent that. This is especially true on meta, where downvotes sometimes indicate disagreement, and disagreed requests can be valuable.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I agree, but the reality is that it does, and I just had two questions deleted as a consequence (I've cast a vote to undelete and will see what the relevant community thinks of it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.

As rene commented, every week when the script is run, all questions that meet the deletion criteria are deleted. This includes questions that were previously deleted under the same specific set of criteria and subsequently undeleted.

This means that if such a question gets undeleted, it needs to be fixed so that the deletion criteria no longer apply, or it will be immediately re-deleted.